# Between clause doesn't work if the variable is dynamic in php and mysql query

Tags: php, mysql

I have this following query:

```
SELECT routes.line as RouteLine , 
       tickets.departure_date as DepartureDate

 FROM tickets
 INNER JOIN routes
 ON tickets.route_code = routes.code
 WHERE tickets.departure_date 
     BETWEEN '2015-03-04' AND '2015-03-05'";
```

and php variable:

```
$from = "2015-03-04";
$to = "2015-03-05";
```

The above sql query is working fine when I declare the date is static but when I change the value of dates by this: `BETWEEN '$from' AND '$to'` I get no results. Why is this happen???

I tried to do this: `BETWEEN '"$from"' AND '"$to"'` but the I still get nothing. What is wrong? :'-(

Comment: Try this :
BETWEEN DATE($from) AND DATE($to)

Comment: Try to echo your sql query and check if have all quotes around dates.

Comment: If you like, consider following this simple two-step course of action: 1. If you have not already done so, provide proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) so that we can more easily replicate the problem. 2. If you have not already done so, provide a desired result set that corresponds with the information provided in step 1.

Comment: echo that entire query and copy paste in msqlyog or phpmyadmin.  Also do check your database,check whthr really any records falls in those dates?

Comment: The SQL itself looks fine, as does what you are attempting to do.  The problem almost certainly lies in your PHP code, which you have not shown.